# Conditional passing of a default parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, window

I'm coming up against 'window is undefined' errors while using React and Gatsby, so I want to conditionally pass a default value to my function parameter:

`function useEventListener(element = window) {`

I only want the function to be able to run if 'window' exists, and wrapping the contents of useEventListener inside an if statement isn't enough to avoid the error.

I was wondering if there is some way of doing it something like:

`const windowDefined = () => typeof window !== "undefined";`

`function useEventListener(windowDefined ? element = window : element) {`

Answer (score 0):

can't you do the same inside the function, check it the parameter passed is undefined or not and return empty if it is?

```
function useEventListener( element) {
if(element){
return something
}
else{
return null
}
}
```

or wrap the whole function itself in a if condition and by default parameter it means it will work only if you don't pass a value,

please give more context for the question and usecase also

Answer (score 0):

You could use a guard clause for this. If you just want the function to be prevented from running if `window` exists, the code would look like this:

```
function useEventListener() {
    if (!window) return null

    //function code here
}
```